# how to rewrite the update query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I don't have the `EXPLAIN` plan for the below query but the where condition is using a primary index. but it takes so much time to execute kindly suggest better option to increase the performance.

```
UPDATE `customer_entity` 
SET `website_id` = ?, `email` = ?, `group_id` = ?, `store_id` = ?,
    `created_at` = ?, `updated_at` = ?, `disable_auto_group_change` = ?, 
    `firstname` = ?, `lastname` = ?, `password_hash` = ?, `rp_token` = ?, 
    `rp_token_created_at` = ?, `confirmation` = ?, `gender` = ?,
    `failures_num` = ?, `first_failure` = ?, `lock_expires` = ?,
    `contact_no` = ?, `alt_mobile_no` = ?, `employee_code` = ?,
    `mobileapp_customer_id` = ? 
WHERE (`entity_id`=?)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248307/discussion-between-meriton-issac-and-ysth).

Comment: It sounds like `entity_id` is not the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE customer_entity` to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would debug that query this way:

1. Try to run the `EXPLAIN` to see the estimated execution plan.
   You say you are not able to do this - that's a shame, because then you are a bit more in the dark.
2. Run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` while this query is running.
   There might be some insights here as to what is going on.
   Is the database server completely flooded? Is the query in question waiting for another lock on the table?
3. Check performance metrics on the server. If you are using a managed database via a cloud provider, they typically have statistics that shows CPU, Memory, Disk IO usage etc.
   It might show that your database is forced to its knees.
4. In MySQL, writes (this includes UPDATE-statements) are slowed down if the table has many indexes. Does the table contain more indexes than usual?
5. Run `FLUSH STATUS` -> [Run you query] -> `SHOW STATUS` to see if the status variables include valuable information about the query just run.
   The `EXPLAIN` tells you what the *estimated* query execution plan is.
   STATUS tells you what the *actual* execution just did.

I do not think that an update by primary key would take 39 minutes no matter how many rows there is, so I would look for other clues.

Comment: updates in mysql innodb are not slowed by multiple indexes, unless the values indexed are changed.  aiui this is different from postgres where all indexes must be updated whenever any change occurs